# Oddsmakers, Betmakers and Sportsbooks: Who does what?

Tags: terminology, betting

Brand new to sports betting here, and am wondering if there is a technical difference between:

- The *oddsmaker*; and
- The *betmaker*; and
- The *sportsbook*

These terms seem interchangeable on some sites/documents, yet seem to be *slightly* different concepts on others. I'm talking about legal betting organizations here, not backroom bookies, etc.

Comment: Interchangeability is likely to happen when one agent or agency or section has a combined rule, say by both determining odds and taking bets. As for definition, n answer yet.

Comment: Ah thanks @Nij (+1) so it sounds like the *sportsbook* is the "agent", the *oddsmakers* is the odds/stats expert that sets the odds, and the *betmaker* is an employee of the sportsbook that actually accepts the bet perhaps? Thanks again!

Comment: I might have presumed something similar based on the names and a general understanding of the system for at least one major betting agency, but I do not know for sure, and would not consider that presumption to be an effective answer until I find evidence to support it. *Also note a typo in first comment: combined role \rule.*